# Web Scraping with Python - html table

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table

I try to scrape many tables from the following tables and create .csv files for each of them. Could somebody help me to adjust the code to only extract the main table in the middle of the page? (the html source seems to be a bit messy)

http://www.qualitycheck.org/QualityReportHistory.aspx?hcoid=3322#Top

The resulting .csv files always include the information I want, but there is a lot of other stuff I don't want there.

Here is my code:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrape_url(url):
    html = urlopen(url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = bsObj.findAll("table",{"class":"MainContent"})[0]
    rows=table.findAll("tr")
    return rows

def write_csv_data(path, rows):
    csvFile = open(path, 'wt')
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    try:
        for row in rows:
            csvRow=[]
            for cell in row.findAll(['tr']):
                csvRow.append(cell.get_text())
                writer.writerow(csvRow)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
         pass


for i in ("3322#Top",   "1481#Top", "1522#Top"):
    url = "http://www.qualitycheck.org/QualityReportHistory.aspx?hcoid={}".format(i)
    csv_path = "/Users/Files/file-{}.csv".format(i)

    rows = scrape_url(url)
    write_csv_data(csv_path, rows)
```

Any hints?

Thanks a lot!
Max

Comment: Could you not just change this to get the table you want?   `bsObj.findAll("table",{"class":"MainContent"})[0]` That just gets the first table it finds

Comment: It finds the right table, but how can I change the repetition of every single element in my csv file?
It is like:
Program1
Program1Program2
Program1Program2Program3....

Comment: It looks like you don't need your nested loop. You're doing `for each row... for each cell in row`... It looks like you just need the outer for loop

Comment: Ok, but then I only get empty cells.